# Find list of dates in a table closest to specific date from different table.

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of unique ID's in one table that has a date column. Example:

```
     TABLE1
 ID          Date
 0           2018-01-01
 1           2018-01-05
 2           2018-01-15
 3           2018-01-06
 4           2018-01-09
 5           2018-01-12
 6           2018-01-15
 7           2018-01-02
 8           2018-01-04
 9           2018-02-25
```

Then in another table I have a list of different values that appear multiple times for each ID with various dates.

```
         TABLE 2
ID       Value       Date
0        18          2017-11-28
0        24          2017-12-29
0        28          2018-01-06
1        455         2018-01-03
1        468         2018-01-16
2        55          2018-01-03
3        100         2017-12-27
3        110         2018-01-04
3        119         2018-01-10
3        128         2018-01-30
4        223         2018-01-01
4        250         2018-01-09
4        258         2018-01-11
```

etc

I want to find the value in table 2 that is closest to the unique date in table 1. 
Sometimes table 2 does contain a value that matches the date exactly and I have had no problem in pulling through those values. But I can't work out the code to pull through the value closest to the date requested from table 1.

My desired result based on the examples above would be

```
ID          Value          Date
0           24             2017-12-29
1           455            2018-01-03
2           55             2018-01-03
3           110            2018-01-04
4           250            2018-01-09
```

Since I can easily find the ID's with an exact match, one thing I have tried is taking the ID's that don't have an exact date match and placing them with their corresponding values into a temporary table. Then trying to find the values where I need the closest possible match, but it's here that I'm not sure where to begin on the coding of that.

Apologies if I'm missing a basic function or clause for this, I'm still learning!

Comment: If you're looking for 2nd January, and the only data available is 1st Jan and 3rd Jan, which do you want?  Is there a maximum distance you would consider?  *(If the closest values are +1 year and -1 year, do you still want one of them?)*  Do you know the maximum realistic gap between values?  *(That will help optimise the search over large data-sets)*  Also, which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below would be one method:

```
WITH Table1 AS(
    SELECT ID, CONVERT(date, datecolumn) DateColumn
    FROM (VALUES (0,'20180101'),
                 (1,'20180105'),
                 (2,'20180115'),
                 (3,'20180106'),
                 (4,'20180109'),
                 (5,'20180112'),
                 (6,'20180115'),
                 (7,'20180102'),
                 (8,'20180104'),
                 (9,'20180225')) V(ID, DateColumn)),
Table2 AS(
    SELECT ID, [value], CONVERT(date, datecolumn) DateColumn
    FROM (VALUES (0,18 ,'2017-11-28'),
                 (0,24 ,'2017-12-29'),
                 (0,28 ,'2018-01-06'),
                 (1,455,'2018-01-03'),
                 (1,468,'2018-01-16'),
                 (2,55 ,'2018-01-03'),
                 (3,100,'2017-12-27'),
                 (3,110,'2018-01-04'),
                 (3,119,'2018-01-10'),
                 (3,128,'2018-01-30'),
                 (4,223,'2018-01-01'),
                 (4,250,'2018-01-09'),
                 (4,258,'2018-01-11')) V(ID, [Value],DateColumn))
SELECT T1.ID,
       T2.[Value],
       T2.DateColumn
FROM Table1 T1
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                  FROM Table2 ca
                  WHERE T1.ID = ca.ID
                  ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, ca.DateColumn, T1.DateColumn))) T2;
```

Note that if the difference is days is the same, the row returned will be random (and could differ each time the query is run). For example, if `Table` had the date `20180804` and `Table2` had the dates `20180803` and `20180805` they would both have the value `1` for `ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, ca.DateColumn, T1.DateColumn))`. You therefore might need to include additional logic in your `ORDER BY` to ensure consistent results.

Comment: Mmmm, `CROSS APPLY`, I miss SQL Server for so many reasons :)

Comment: @MatBailie what do you use now then?

Comment: Umm, almost Anything else ;)  PySpark/Hive, BigQuery, RedShift, PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, Oracle, TeraData.  But none of the clients I work with ever seem to use SQL Server (except one, for whom I'm not doing any DB work...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this has worked for me! Luckily my dates in the second table are spread out over months and years (unlike my examples where I used days close to each other for ease of explaining), so there's very little risk of two dates being exactly apart. But anyone else using this should make a note of such.

Answer (score 1):

dude.

I'll say a couple of things here for you to consider, since SQL Server is not my comfort zone, while SQL itself is.

---

First of all, I'd join TABLE1 with TABLE2 per ID. That way, I can specify on my `SELECT` clause the following tuple:

```
SELECT ID, Value, DateDiff(d, T1.Date, T2.Date) qt_diff_days
```

Obviously, depending on the precision of the dates kept there, rather they have times or not, you can change the date field on `DateDiff` function.

Going forward, I'd also make this date difference an absolute number (to resolve positive / negative differences and consider only the elapsed time).

After that, and that's where it gets tricky because I don't know the SQL Server version you're using, but basically I'd use a `ROW_NUMBER` window function to rank all my lines per difference. Something like the following:

```
SELECT
  ID, Value, Abs(DateDiff(d, T1.Date, T2.Date)) qt_diff_days,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Abs(DateDiff(d, T1.Date, T2.Date)) ASC) nu_row
```

> [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Numbers the output of a result set. More specifically, returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

If you could run `ROW_NUMBER` properly, you should notice the query will rank it's data per ID, starting with `1` and increasing this ranking by it's difference between both dates, reseting it's rank to `1` when ID changes.

---

After that, all you need to do is select only those lines where `nu_row` equals to `1`. I'd use a CTE to that.

> [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Specifies a temporary named result set, known as a common table expression (CTE).